# How to sequence pipeline execution trigger in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I am working on a migration project where I have a few SQL Server Integration Service projects that will be moved to Azure Data Factory. While I go through this we have a few jobs scheduled via SQL Server Agent which has multiple steps. If were to replicate the same using Azure Data Factory triggers is there a way to group multiple pipelines together and sequence the execution accordingly like we have multiple job steps in SQL Server Agents.

For instance:

1. Load all of the lookup tables
2. Load all of the staging tables
3. Load all of the dimension tables
4. Load Fact table

Please guide in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Execute Pipeline Activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-execute-pipeline-activity) to build a master pipeline that runs your other pipelines. eg

[image]

Comment: Hi @David Browne, Is there a way to group together a few pipelines and add a trigger on them so they run in a sequence?

Comment: Yes.  The Execute Pipeline Activity.  See updated answer.